# How to rerun terminated autosys jobs?

Tags: ca, autosys

I want to run several autosys jobs in such a case, if it's running more than 30 min, terminate it and automatically rerun it. I tried the followlling jil:

```
n_retrys:3
term_run_time:30
```

But this jil only terminates the job after 30 min, no post rerun. Is there any solution of such a case in jil?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please carefully read the description of the autosys tag, and then clarify how your question meets the criteria described there regarding being programming related.

Comment: @KenWhite, thanks for reminding, but it's a legacy job I get from previous project, the process job sometimes run into stuck and delay other jobs, what I try to implement is what I did manually, kill the stuck job and rerun it. I know there is solution to program on original script instead of jil. But it's not recommended in an organization.

Comment: As I said, the tag description is very specific. Please read the tag description carefully, and then [edit] your post to make it clear how this is a programming related question. Again, the tag description is quite specific: **Unless you are asking a programming question about integration with the AutoSys SDK, your question is likely off-topic**. It's irrelevant that it's a legacy job, it's irrelevant that the job gets stuck, and it's irrelevant what you're trying to do to fix it unless it meets this site's guidelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to create a helper job that runs on the condition of the termination of your original job and restarts it for you.

```
insert_job: Main_Job_Restarter
job_type: c
command: sendevent -E FORCE_STARTJOB Main_Job
condition: terminated(Main_Job)
```

With this, you can remove the n_retrys attribute from your original job but leave the term_run_time intact.

Comment: very reasonable solution, would be exactly what I need. But is there any way we can do this inside the same jil?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the n_retrys is set to restart the job only in case of "FAILURE" not terminated.
As per the documentation :

The n_retrys attribute specifies the number of times to restart the job after it exits with a FAILURE status.

If you want to re-run and have a time window to run then use the combination of 
**start_times:** 
and 
**run_window:**

This can re-run but irrespective of the status.

Only other way to comply with the requirement will be to modify the script/binary used in command job to include retry logic internally.